# Ошибка работы Composer

Tags: composer

Win 10 Пользуюсь консолью Open Server, в котором он вроде бы должен быть установлен. И после команды git init в папке проекта появляется только файл init, в котором сообщается об ошибках. Вчера вот создались ещё файлы composer.json и install, но так как никаких вопросов в консоли не было, они были удалены. [image: скрины Sunlime Text и Consol OpenServer]

```html
#!/usr/bin/env php

Warning: Phar::mapPhar(-): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 23

Fatal error: Uncaught PharException: unable to open phar for reading "-" in -:23
Stack trace:
#0 -(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in - on line 23
```

Comment: Может поможет в решении  http://plutov.by/post/composer_openserver

Comment: @Fin  можете сказать вы отдельно установили `composer` ? или это дефольтный  `OpenServer`-а?

Comment: отдельно не устанавливал, но как пишут -он должен быть уже установлен в Open Server по умолчанию, как Git. может быть, его настраивать как-то нужно? т.е. файлы install и init создаются, с ошибками, а папка vendor -нет

Answer (score 0):

Папка `vendor` будет после нормального завершения `composer update`.
Краткое решение будет если вы уберете файлы composer из `OpenServer`.
Потом надо скачать и установить `composer` [отсюда](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

После установки уже в любом консоле `windows` зайдите в папку вашего проекта и наберите команду `composer update`. и после работы этой команды у вас будут скачаны и установлены все `зависимости` вашего проекта.

Comment: А куда его устанавливать нужно, в какую папку? В Open Server его и не видно нигде. Если набрать команду в консоли: composer.phar, то в сразу предлагается открыть этот файл, расположенный в  W:\modules\php\PHP-7.0\composer.phar  Open Server сам установлен на диске D т.е. в папке php -7 эти файлы: composer composer.phar надо удалить?

Comment: В папке Openserver найдите 2 файла `composer.json` и `composer.phar`, но не те файлы которые у вас там в проектах, и удалите, а линк который я скинул , оттуда скачайте екзешник и установите его как любая прога в `windows`

Comment: а эти файлы должны быть в модуле php Open Server? Composer.phar есть там, json нет

Comment: Точно вечером скажу, но они должны быть в OpenServer, но не в проектах, если кокой то оставишь то прога сного не установиться , попробуй после удаления этого файла установи `composer`.